# Several limitation classes per one Job Object

Tags: windows, winapi, system-calls, system32

In Windows Job Object can apply some amount of different limitations for processes. These limitations are available through the different job object info classes.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "You can use the SetInformationJobObject function to set several limits in a single call. If you want to establish the limits one at a time or change a subset of the limits, call the QueryInformationJobObject function to obtain the current limits, modify these limits, and then call SetInformationJobObject."

But it's unclear: is it possible to set limitations from more than one job object info class for one job object?

Of course "rich" limit classes wrap the basic, so we have essentially limitations of two classes simultaneously. But I ask about the case of two *non-basic* classes.

Comment: You are probably reading it wrong.  The struct that you pass contains multiple limits.  They will all be set at the same time.  If you want to change just *one* of the limits then you'll have to read the struct first with QIJO, change the one field value of the struct that you care about, then call SIJO.

Comment: @HansPassant I have probably written it wrong. There are different **classes** of limitations (e. g. JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION, JOBOBJECT_BASIC_UI_RESTRICTIONS), what if it's needed to set several classes to one job object? May be such situation is impossible, I'm not sure.

Comment: Obviously that cannot work, the JobObjectInfoClass argument can have only one value.

Comment: You can set multiple different classes of limitations on a single job object, but you do it by calling SetInformationJobObject multiple times.  The paragraph you quote doesn't apply to this situation.